# How to get the values from dynamically generated form using JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a form using the JSON data, but when I'm trying to add `eventlisteners` to the created elements, 
I am unable to get the values of the form generated dynamically. The form contains various input types based on the JSON data.
Any help would be appreciated.
Here is the form I tried to create.

```js
var data = {
  "id": 6,
  "form_name": "Some form",
  "is_archived": false,
  "form_fields": [
    {
      "id": "5cc318416403f",
      "label": "Name",
      "options": [
        ""
      ],
      "required": true,
      "field_type": "textbox"
    },
    {
      "id": "5cc318416404a",
      "label": "Date",
      "options": [
        ""
      ],
      "required": false,
      "field_type": "date"
    },
    {
      "id": "5cc318416404d",
      "label": "What steps did you take?",
      "options": [
        "run","jump","walk"
      ],
      "required": true,
      "field_type": "checkbox"
    },
    {
      "id": "5cc318416404f",
      "label": "Contact details",
      "options": [
        ""
      ],
      "required": false,
      "field_type": "textbox"
    },
    {
      "id": "5cc318416406v",
      "label": "Gender details",
      "options": [
        "Male","Female"
      ],
      "required": false,
      "field_type": "radio"
    }
  ],
  "created_on": "2019-04-26"
}
var div = $(".wrapper");
            var total_fields = Object.keys(data.form_fields).length;
            div.append("<h1>" + data.form_name + '</h1><hr width="70%">');
            var ids = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < total_fields; i++) {
              //console.log(data.form_fields[i].options.length);
              var form_wrapper = jQuery("<div/>", {
                class: "row"
              }).appendTo(".wrapper");
              //form_wrapper.append("<form>");
              form_wrapper.append(
                '<div class="col-25"><label>' + data.form_fields[i].label + "</label></div>"
              );
              var type = data.form_fields[i].field_type;
              if (type == "checkbox") {
                if (data.form_fields[i].options.length > 1) {
                  for (var j = 0; j < data.form_fields[i].options.length; j++) {
                    form_wrapper.append(
                      '<div class="col-75"><input class="floatLabel" name="' +
                        data.form_fields[i].label +
                        '" id = "' +
                        data.form_fields[i].id +
                        '" type = ' +
                        data.form_fields[i].field_type +
                        ">" +
                        data.form_fields[i].options[j] +
                        "</input></div>"
                    );
                  }
                }
                $('#'+data.form_fields[i].id).on('input', function() {
                  // do your stuff
                  console.log("changing");
                });
                //values.push();
              } 
              else if (type == "textarea") {
                form_wrapper.append(
                  '<div class="col-75"><textarea id="'+data.form_fields[i].id+'" placeholder = "' +
                    data.form_fields[i].label +
                    '"></textarea></div>'
                );
                //values.push($("#"+data.form_fields[i].id).val());
              } 
              else if (type == "radio") {
                var radio_value ;
                if (data.form_fields[i].options.length > 1) {
                  for (var j = 0; j < data.form_fields[i].options.length; j++) {
                    form_wrapper.append(
                      '<div class="col-75"><input class="floatLabel" value="'+ data.form_fields[i].options[j] +'" name="' +
                        data.form_fields[i].label +
                        '" type = ' +
                        data.form_fields[i].field_type +
                        ">" +
                        data.form_fields[i].options[j] +
                        "</input></div>"
                    );
                  }

                }
                
              } 
              else {
                form_wrapper.append(
                  '<div class="col-75"><input class="floatLabel" required="' +
                    data.form_fields[i].required +
                    '" id = "' +
                    data.form_fields[i].id +
                    '" type = ' +
                    data.form_fields[i].field_type +
                    "></div>"
                );
                $('#'+data.form_fields[i].id).on('input', function() {
                  // do your stuff
                  console.log("changing");
                });
              }
              ids.push(data.form_fields[i].id);
            }
            form_wrapper.append(
              '<br><input type="submit" id="form_submit" class="sbutton">'
            );
            
            $('#form_submit').click(function(){
              //console.the values.
            });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I do things like that, I always use [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) instead of [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

```
let $field = $('<div class="col-25"><label>' + data.form_fields[i].label + "</label></div>");
$field.on("change", function() { ... });
form_wrapper.append($field);
```

By creating an element with `$('<html>')` you have the newly created element's reference to bind it any event you may like, then you can `appendTo()` the target element(`form_wrapper`) in your case.

Comment: When I try to console.log the value, it's giving undefined!

Comment: I couldn't get the values from the form